# How to connect to wifi if you didnt connect to it before, by python on linux or Windows. (input: SSID, PASSWORD)

Tags: python, linux, windows

How to connect to wifi if you didn't connect to it before, by python on Linux or Windows. (input: SSID, PASSWORD)

Answer (score 0):

from wireless import Wireless

wire = Wireless()
wire.connect(ssid='NAME_OF_YOUR_WIFI',password='YOUR_PASSWORD')

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).